# Why Device or resource busy whent to remove the file?

Tags: linux, ntfs, copy, lsof

`/dev/sda4` is in ntfs file system ,and  mounted on `/mnt/winntfs`  with `ntfsusermap`(the most key point),the post list how to mount ntfs in linux step by step.

[how to mount ntfs in linux step by step](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603153/how-to-make-apache-in-debian-access-the-resource-on-the-windows-ntfs-filesystem)

```
sudo cp -r  mydoc  /mnt/winntfs
ls  /mnt/winntfs
mydoc
ls  /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
analyse  build  cron
```

You can see that i have copied all content in $HOME/mydoc into /mnt/winntfs/mydoc,now i want to remove `/mnt/winntfs/mydoc`.

```
sudo rm -rf  /mnt/winntfs/*
rm: cannot remove '/mnt/winntfs/mydoc': Device or resource busy
lsof | grep -i  "mydoc"
lsof | grep -i  "/mnt/winntfs/mydoc"
```

I want to get the process id number with lsof,and kill the process with id number ,then maybe remove it,but `lsof` command get nothing,why it can be copied some directory ,instead of removing it?How can i remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device or resource is busy because partition is still mounted.
You have to unmount the partition before removing the partition.
Opened terminal and run:

```
sudo umount -f  /mnt/winntfs/mydoc
sudo rm -rf  /mnt/winntfs/*
```